# Best way of showing up the contents

Tags: content

I want something that is easy for new staff to access and has important information for navigating their first few days. It should have the approval process embedded from the beginning to encourage and facilitate content updating.
I have a lot material to read, What would be the best way to put the contents in SharePoint site.

Comment: do you want them read the content on 1st few days or edit first few days?

Comment: Just to read them and if possible, I would like to have hover over too on each link which I provided on the page.

Comment: You want them to read all the pages?

Comment: It depends, I have created one On boarding wiki page and have added the content on the first pages with table of contents, now I want to add pages for each of the table of contents and if possible, I want pop-up for each hyper link so that they can decide whether they want to read the page or not.

Comment: sharepoint online or on prem version of sharepoint?

Comment: On Premise version of SharePoint